# How to set WinSCP default editor to Sublime Text on Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, sublimetext3, winscp, wine

I know that to change the editor I go to Preferences -> Editors and select whatever I want, but how do I set it to Sublime Text 3 ? I'm supposed to write in the external editor the path to launcher of my desired editor, but where's the install path for sublime? If I just write sublime in that input field, I get an error that it doesn't find such a thing on my system (I can start it through terminal with that command).

Note that I'm using WinSCP with wine (that's obvious, I suppose). Any help appriciated :)

Comment: For me the binary is located in **/opt/sublime_text/** with name sublime_text on Linux Mint. As a Linux alternative to WinSCP you can use [filezilla client](https://filezilla-project.org/) so that you don't need to use wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command ***subl*** that is located in ***/usr/bin/subl*** (*/usr/bin* is in *$PATH*).

For me the executable is located in */opt/sublime_text/* on Linux Mint, but maybe is better to use the *subl* command.

Answer (score 1):

1) Go to Edit -> Preferences and navigate to File Editing.

2) Choose Use custom editor

3) Write executable file path of Sublime Text 2.
(for ex: /usr/bin/subl)

4)Close the dialog by pressing OK.

5) Go to Filetype association and write executable file path here.
(for ex: php /usr/bin/subl)

6) Done